# How to sniff packets using netfilter without netfilter_queue

Tags: c, packet-sniffers, netfilter

I am working on a user-mode firewall using **netfilter**, for new linux machine (kernel 5), but I want it to also support old kernels.
I don't want to include the dependency of `netfilter_queue`, so I try to use only raw netlink packets. I didn't manage to program a working POC, but I found that [reqrypt](https://github.com/basil00/reqrypt/blob/master/src/linux/capture.c) and also [libpcap](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/b284d14cef177ddd70a3ae64ba6e7b88f72cf822/pcap-netfilter-linux.c) do similar things to what I seek.

This is what I have done so far:

- Create netlink socket:

```c
socket_netfilter = socket(AF_NETLINK, SOCK_RAW, NETLINK_NETFILTER);
```

- Bind it with:

```c
nl_addr.nl_family = AF_NETLINK;
nl_addr.nl_pid = getpid();
nl_addr.nl_groups = 0xffff; // Listen to everything for POC
```

- Bind to `Pf_INET`:
- Set to copy mode (`NFQNL_COPY_PACKET`)
- Attach to queue
- Sniff packets using: - **This part hangs (no packet is received)**

```c
char nl_buff[ETH_DATA_LEN + sizeof(struct ethhdr) + sizeof(struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr)];
struct sockaddr_nl nl_addr;
socklen_t nl_addr_len = sizeof(nl_addr);
int result = recvfrom(socket_netfilter, nl_buff, sizeof(nl_buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&nl_addr, &nl_addr_len);
```

- Process packet
- Drop relevant packets using 'set_verdict'

My code is almost identical to [reqrypt](https://github.com/basil00/reqrypt/blob/master/src/linux/capture.c), but I can't figure out why mine hangs on `recvfrom`. I would also appreciate documentations or references to similar projects.

Comment: When talking about things this low-level, it does help to specify the OS you're working with.